# Swift: In-app email freezes for few seconds and throws exception

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I'm trying to add in-app email feature to my application. I found some code online for it but when I run  the app, it just freezes for few seconds and throws an exception. Below is the code I used

```
    @IBAction func sendMail(sender: AnyObject) {
    let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
    }
}

func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["someone@somewhere.com"])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("Sending you an in-app e-mail...")
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Body", isHTML: false)

    return mailComposerVC
}

func showSendMailErrorAlert() {
    let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    sendMailErrorAlert.show()
}

// MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate Method
func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError!) {
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

And the exception is:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/Keyboard/UIKeyboardTaskQueue.m:374
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'
```

Some post suggested that we need to cycle the MFMailComposeViewController after each use. But I really have no idea on how to implement that.

Comment: The code ([which you lifted straight from here](http://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/08/25/send-email-in-app-using-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-with-swift/)) looks correct to me. Looking at your error, it says "`may only be called from the main thread.'`".  Are you bringing up this view controller on a different thread (e.g. via `dispatch_async` or some other thread-spawning method)??

Comment: @MichaelDautermann No I didn't use 'dispatch_async' to call this view controller. I'm just calling this on a button click in the main view controller.

Comment: You say when you run the app it freezes for a few seconds and then crashes. Is this after you press the mail button? - it doesn't sound like it. This crash is definitely related to executing on another thread - which line does it crash on? Examine the stack trace

Comment: @Paulw11 No it's not when I click the Send button, this email view controller pops up and after few seconds it freezes and throws exception. I have just created a sample project and tried implementing this code but still the same problem. I'm a beginner in Swift, so I'm not sure on which thread it is executing. I hope you understand.

Comment: Can you make that sample project available (via GitHub or BitBucket) and edit your question to show the link to it?  I have a feeling it's just an oversight somewhere in your code.

Comment: I pasted your code into a sample application and it works perfectly, so there is a problem somewhere else

Comment: @Paulw11 I found the issue. The problem is with iOS 8.1. I ran it on iOS 7.1 simulator and it worked! Thank you all:)